# how to sort date in a file such that the data in a linked file remains linked to the sorted data Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, sorting

I am trying to get data that is in testfile1 sorted into date order, and the data that is in the file which is linked to testfile1 "moves" with it.
testfile1 has 3 columns. Column A contains random order dates. Columns B and C hold descriptions and values (respectively) relevant to the dates in Column A. Currently set up with 6 rows of random dates (Rows 3 to 8) plus descriptions and values in the relevant columns.
[image]

```
testfile2 also contains 3 columns, but only 2 Rows.
'Column A, Row 1 is =[testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$5
'Column B, Row 1 is =[testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$5 and
'Column C, Row 1 is =[testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$5
'Row 2 contains =[testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$8,       ' 
[testfile1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$B$8 and =[testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$C$8 in         Columns 'A to C respectively
```

[image]

```
sub macro1()
Range("A2:C7").Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort.SortFields.Add    Key:=Range("A2"), _
    SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A2:C7")
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

I need to be able to sort the data in testfile1 into date order (Column A) and for the data in testfile2 to relate to the new position of the data in testfile1.

I've tried every combination of [testfile 1.xlsx]Sheet1'!$A$4, $A4, A$4 and just plain A4 in testfile2. In each and every case, the data in testfile2 continues to relate to the original location, including "naming" the Row data.
The result:
[image]

Comes out looking like this:-
[image]
As you can see the formula has remaind the same, and now refers to the incorrect data.

I did find a link earlier (in stackoverflow) which suggested using Index and Match, but initially I didn't understand the syntax, and couldn't ghet it to work. Since then I've slept on it, and I think!! I know what I was doing wrong. However, I didn't make a note of the suggested syntax, and now I can't find it again. help!!!

Comment: Your example data might be better illustrated for us as an actual table, paste a screenshot clipping for example, or lay it out in table format (neatly) here.  Something else is you haven't asked the question clearly in the question body itself - you've just left it in the title.  The title contains some _very_ relevant information regarding your requirement, that you expect the two files to remain "linked".  I would ask you to consider how someone else would read your question, someone who doesn't know what exactly it is you want - flesh it out a bit!

Comment: Did you try using named cells?

Comment: No I haven't tried named cells. Not sure how that would work in a vba programme?

Comment: Never mind - put that out before testing...

Comment: Yep, I've tried that, but it doesn't appear to have made any difference. The second file still refers to the original rows i.e.now holds the incorrect information. I realise that the problem lies with the links - not the sort. Doing it with VBA, or doing it "manually" makes no difference. If it won't work "manually" it won't work in a programme, I'm down to thinking a lot of "cutting and pasting" is going to be involved!!!

Comment: I found a possible answer here on stackoverflow, where someone had suggested using Index and Match in testfile2 instead of cel references. Unfortunately I can't find the question or the answer again. Any ideas???

Comment: I think I may have solved the problem by "naming" the Rows and then using VBA to manipulate the "Name Manager" to change the A1R1 references to the new location. Unless anyone else has any ideas, I'm going to run with this.